# How to connect with application server?

Tags: express, sockets, server, backend

I have 3 application servers running on 3 different ports doing the same thing. I want a socket connection between the client and a free application server. How to pass the information of the free server's port number so I can achieve a socket connection. Should I give the client the port number of the free application server?

Currently I am giving the client the port information and achieving a socket connection with the app server.

I am very new to web development and please forgive me for my poor English.

Comment: Are you looking for _load balancing_? Many web servers and reverse proxy provide this functionality. Also, Node.js has a built-in cluster module to distribute requests to worker processes.

Comment: I do have a load balancer, but I need another service to also do some route directing